# Order an array which contains OpenStructs by another array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have an array which contains OpenStruct elements.

I want to sort them by the id attribute, but not in a numeric order, which I can achieve by:

```
a.sort! { |x,y| x.id <=> y.id }
```

The order I need, as no logic, so I have an array, lets say:

```
order = ['4','32','1','3','5']
```

And I want to order my `a` array in that way.

All data contained in each `a[x]` is an OpenStruct which has an `.id` attribute.

Comment: Looks like homework, what have you tried so far?

Comment: No, not homework. Too old for that. It's work-work. I've tried things like `{ |x| order.index <=> x.id }`, and others ways I found, but I think it's maybe everything not working because of using OpenStruct inside. Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear whether you have numbers or strings as the attribute. If the former, then do

```
order.map!(&:to_i)
```

first. Then do:

```
a.sort_by!{|e| order.index(e.id)}
```

If there are no duplicates, do instead:

```
order & a.map(&:id)
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You mean my second way?

Comment: This works just fine if the array to order is just an array of arrays. Works on console, but once I use OpenStruct is just fails silently. I will improve my question to clarify.

Comment: it turns out that I needed to convert to integer the `order.index(e.id)` in the block: `a.sort_by!{ |e| order.index(e.id).to_i }`. I think it was maybe because some ids weren't cached in the `order` array. Could that be?